# WebAPI 2 with OWIN middleware and token-based authentication: OPTIONS request returns "unsupported_grant_type" error

Tags: authentication, oauth

WEbAPI provides end-point for authentication request: http:\...\token

Authentication request should be sent using Method "POST" and Body like

```
"grant_type=password&username=name&password=mypassword"
```

This WebAPI is used by Front-End which is written using AngularJS.
Sometimes before sending "POST" request with valid Body, a "OPTIONS" request is sent without Body.
As result the following error is returned by WebAPI:

```
Status: 400
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Is there any solution which can be implemented on Server-side? (in WebAPI)

HTTP Request Method: OPTIONS

```
Request Header:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,uk;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Host:...
Origin:...
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36

Response Header:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 34
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 18:05:09 GMT
```

Answer (score 18):

I just ran into the same issue..I'm using ember and ember-simple-auth.  Any preflight requests OPTIONS to the /token endpoint were resulting in a 400 HTTP response and the body had the well known: {error: "unsuported_grant_type"}.

**SOLUTION:**

I inherit from: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and override the MatchEndpoint function:

```
public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.OwinContext.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" && context.IsTokenEndpoint)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] {"POST"});
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "accept", "authorization", "content-type" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.RequestCompleted();

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);        }
```

That seems to take care of it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Question - first line inside the `if` statement - should that be `OwinContext.Response` instead of `OwinContext.Request`?

Comment: It should be `OwinContext.Request` because you're interrogating the incoming request.

Comment: Just to be clear @WojciechWieroński, you're intentionally adding one new header to the request and two new headers to the response?

Comment: @JamesThurley and @GalagticCowboy , copy and paste blunder...I misinterpreted the part of the `if` in the previous question.  It SHOULD Be `Response`, adding anything to the request is useless as it's already arrived.  I'll update the original solution.

Comment: If you are using angularjs/jQuery or similar with CORS this is probably the solution you are looking for !

Comment: FYI, you can use `return Task.CompletedTask` instead. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when I forgot to add `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the request header.

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to test my api with Fiddler and wasn't providing the data in the correct format in the Request Body section. Be sure it's added as a key value list separated by '&'.

```
grant_type=password&username=testUsername&password=testPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case *`OPTIONS`* is a CORS preflight request. It is sent in order to determine whether the actual request (`POST`) is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted if uses methods other than `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST` or sets custom headers.

In order to avoid a 400 HTTP response, in your Startup class you should enable CORS for the OWIN middleware using `UseCors` extension method and define your custom `System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy`.

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;

namespace AuthorizationServer
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {     

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally agree Alberto, however the problem here is the actual OPTIONS preflight request (to the token endpoint) is being rejected because the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" isn't being returned for the aforementioned VERB.  That being said,  the CORS config at startup is obviously a prerequisite for all the other verbs and works as expected.

Comment: Just a little addition: the order matters. `UseCors` should go first. Thaks for your answer, it helped me to find this out.

Comment: IAppBuilder does not have UseCors method, this is a configuration method.